# ON CONFLICT not even compile with error syntax?

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm not so sure if this is a problem of SQLite version I'm using. But actually I'm not using native SQLite (dll) directly, what I'm using is the `System.Data.SQLite` version `1.0.108.0` and looks like this is the only version (latest) for the .NET 4.5 that my app targets.

So I'm wondering if that version of `System.Data.SQLite` supports `ON CONFLICT`?

Here is just the basic query with `ON CONFLICT`:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME) VALUES('C1','N1') 
ON CONFLICT(CUSTOMER_ID) 
DO UPDATE SET CUSTOMER_NAME=excluded.CUSTOMER_NAME
```

But it throws an error saying like this:

> near "ON": syntax error:

Comment: I'd guess it's due to *UPSERT syntax was added to SQLite with version 3.24.0 (2018-06-04).*

Comment: Please look up the syntax. Even if it supports  `on conflict` it does not continue like this `(CUSTOMER_ID)`

Comment: @juergend, it does appear to support that syntax from [upsert](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) `INSERT INTO phonebook(name,phonenumber) VALUES('Alice','704-555-1212')
  ON CONFLICT(name) DO UPDATE SET phonenumber=excluded.phonenumber;`

Comment: @MikeT thank you, that's what I've read about, but as I said in my question, I don't use native SQLite dll, so I'm not so sure about the underlying version the `System.Data.SQLite` uses. Looks like `System.Data.SQLite` does not support yet?

Comment: @juergend please see the comment of MikeT, that's also the sample example I've learnt from to build my query, I did not invent the query myself.

Comment: The sqlite_version() function returns the version string for the SQLite library that is running. This function is an SQL wrapper around the sqlite3_libversion() C-interface. [Core Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#sqlite_version) may be of use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get a `near "ON": syntax error:` if the SQlite version is below 3.24.0 (which has only recently been released).

You could use `SELECT sqlite_version();` to retrieve the version of SQLite and thus determine if your version of SQLite is too low.

The syntax appears to match the syntax of an example found at [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Upsert](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) as per :-

```
SELECT sqlite_version();
CREATE TABLE phonebook(name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, phonenumber TEXT);
INSERT INTO phonebook(name,phonenumber) VALUES('Alice','704-555-1212')
  ON CONFLICT(name) DO UPDATE SET phonenumber=excluded.phonenumber;
```

- Note version check added for demonstration.

Running this example on a *too-low* version of SQLite results in :-

> ```
> SELECT sqlite_version()
> > OK
> > Time: 0s
>
>
> CREATE TABLE phonebook(name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, phonenumber TEXT)
> > OK
> > Time: 0.336s
>
>
> INSERT INTO phonebook(name,phonenumber) VALUES('Alice','704-555-1212')
>       ON CONFLICT(name) DO UPDATE SET phonenumber=excluded.phonenumber
> > near "ON": syntax error
> > Time: 0s
> ```

and :-

[image]

Comment: yes looks like it's the version issue, so really `System.Data.SQLite` has not supported the new syntax yet, because the only version targeting .NET 4.5 is what I'm using. I doubt that it will not probably be updated in future to be in sync with the native SQLite.

Comment: @Hopeless, I don't have anything with 3.24.0, otherwise I'd have run and shown it working.